# can overflow: hidden; work with inline-blocks?

Tags: css

I'm trying to put two divs with 50% width beside one another, they are inline-blocks.

The problem is, I also wish to add other elements that affect the width, such as margin, padding, borders, etc. I am quite alright to have a few pixels to be hidden off the side of the window. (In fact, I'd prefer it)

Whats the trick exactly?
How can I have two inline divs that don't stack on top of each other when they hit the maximum width of their parent. Is there some default positioning that inline-blocks have?

EDIT: Here is an example of code. It seems rather simple to me, but they just wont line up.

```css
.parent {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
.child {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">content</div>
  <div class="child">content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you please add your code ?

Comment: provide some codes bro

Comment: Please don't down-vote the question so quickly. If you read it more carefully you could answer it very easily without an example of code. (As did Mike, below)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For padding and borders you can use `box-sizing: border-box;` on your child element.

border-box: "The width and height properties (and min/max properties) includes content, padding and border, but not the margin"

source: [box-sizing](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp)

I think for margin you need to cut some space off your .children. For example: `width: 49.5%; margin: 1%;`

Comment: "but not the margin" Thank you! That explains it.
I had to go with a border. The padding seemed to get ignored when i added box-sizing.

Comment: Padding seems to work just fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/mblander/z8p3drcg/1/

Answer (score 1):

The reason they won't stack is because you have set the margin to `1px` and then the width to be `50%` of the available width. So each child was in fact `50% + 1px + 1px` (for left and right) in width which would exceed the available width of `100%` by `4px`.

Try either with padding, or margin, or reduce the width of the parents. You could also do:

```
width: calc(50% - 2px);
```

Also, the nature of `inline-block` makes it trickier to align elements next to each other if they add up to exactly (or near) 100%.

You can solve this by either setting the parent to have a font-size of 0 and the children to anything greater than 0. Or, you could set each child to `float: left`

[**Demo 1**](https://jsfiddle.net/01wguejv/) (using floats)

[**Demo 2**](https://jsfiddle.net/01wguejv/1/) (using floats, and calc())

[**Demo 3**](https://jsfiddle.net/01wguejv/2/) (setting font-size to 0)

Comment: @stephen check http://caniuse.com/#search=calc whether you can use calc in your browser or not

Comment: I've never seen calc before. That will/could come in handy, but is it supported across all browsers?

Comment: @Stephen, all modern browsers, yes. It doesn't work on IE8. It's quite safe to use, I would say.

Answer (score 0):

As Mike suggested, try to use `box-sizing: border-box`.it will work only if you specify padding instead of margin.

But in this case, even with padding and border-box, still you would not be able to place them side by side as inline-block elements create a small gap in between..

More you can find out https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

If you are ok with few pixels to be hidden off the side of the window, you can add `white-space: nowrap;` to the parent.

```
.parent {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
.child {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 1%;
}
```

Comment: using white-space: nowrap; seems to work. Is this also supported across all browsers?

Comment: it's there for quite long time and all browsers must support it.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, these solutions seemed to be the most reliable:

1. `width: calc(50% - 2px)` (Worked with `float: left;`)
2. `border-sizing: border-box;` (Worked with `border: 1px solid #fff;`)
3. `white-space: nowrap;` (worked circumstantially.)

Thank you to everyone who has contributed.
This was the sort of clarity I was looking for. Knowing multiple ways to solve this issue is abundantly helpful.